# What does xorq do in a register?

Tags: ssh, 64-bit, bit, cpu-registers, systems-programming

I'm somewhat confident I understand XOR, which is commonly used to default values to zero, if you compare two of the same values with xor, it sets it to 0, if they're different the result is 1.

If you have the following

| Location | Value |
| --- | --- |
| %rax | 0xa |
| %rbx | 0x3 |
| %rcx | 0x9 |

```
xorq   %rcx,%rbx
```

Then what would this following command do? I can't see any documentation for xorq (only xor), and I know that all these x64 registers are 8 bytes, I guess I'm just confused what this function would do, from my recollection, I think it would set %rbx to a new value?

Answer (score 0):

In [AT&T](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_assembly_language#Syntax) syntax, most assembly-code instructions have a single-character suffix denoting the size of the operand:

| C declaration | Intel data type | Assembly-code suffix | Size (bytes) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| char | Byte | b | 1 |
| short | Word | w | 2 |
| int | Double word | l | 4 |
| long | Quad word | q | 8 |
| char * | Quad word | q | 8 |
| float | Single precision | s | 4 |
| double | Double precision | l | 8 |

In general, the size could be inferred from the size of the registers but consider the examples below that move immediate (constant) values into memory location at the address stored in EBX, you have to direct the assembler about the size:

> For example:
>
> ```
> movb $2, (%ebx)   /* Move 2 into the single byte at the address stored in EBX. */
> movw $2, (%ebx)   /* Move the 16-bit integer representation of 2 into the 2 bytes starting at the address in EBX. */
> movl $2, (%ebx)   /* Move the 32-bit integer representation of 2 into the 4 bytes starting at the address in EBX. */
> ```

So, your example will just bitwise `XOR` (exclusive `OR`) `%rbx` and `%rcx` registers and store the result in `%rbx` (`%rbx = %rbx ^ %rcx`).

The operand size doesn't affect much in this case but let's see another example where we zero-out only the low-order byte of `%rax`:

**test.s:**

```
.global _start

.text
_start:
    mov $-1, %rax
    xorb $-1, %al

# exit(0)
    mov $60, %rax
    xor %rdi, %rdi
    syscall
```

**Compile it:**

```
# gcc -nostdlib test.s
```

**Check using `gdb` session:**

```
# gdb -q ./a.out 
Reading symbols from /root/a.out...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
(gdb) b _start
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4000d4
(gdb) run
Starting program: /root/./a.out 

Breakpoint 1, 0x00000000004000d4 in _start ()
(gdb) disas
Dump of assembler code for function _start:
=> 0x00000000004000d4 <+0>: mov    $0xffffffffffffffff,%rax
   0x00000000004000db <+7>: xor    $0xff,%al
   0x00000000004000dd <+9>: mov    $0x3c,%rax
   0x00000000004000e4 <+16>:    xor    %rdi,%rdi
   0x00000000004000e7 <+19>:    syscall 
End of assembler dump.
(gdb) info reg $rax $al
rax            0x0  0
al             0x0  0
(gdb) ni
0x00000000004000db in _start ()
(gdb) info reg $rax $al
rax            0xffffffffffffffff   -1
al             0xff -1
(gdb) ni
0x00000000004000dd in _start ()
(gdb) info reg $rax $al
rax            0xffffffffffffff00   -256     <----- only the lower byte was xor'ed
al             0x0  0
```

**References:**

- [x86 Assembly Guide - Operation Suffixes](https://www.cs.yale.edu/flint/cs421/papers/x86-asm/asm.html)